# Music Player that loads automatically music from folder

Tags: sync, itunes, music, cloud

I have a folder with music that synchronizes songs that I via a cloud service. I was using itunes but it turned boring and monotonous because I needed to scan for new music  every time new music was added. Is there a music player that automatically adds music to its playlist as soon as a new song is added to the folder?

Or maybe some feature to scan folder every time the music player is opened? I couldn't find this option in itunes (Win 7).

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Rhythmbox, Clementine, basically anything but iTunes I would think. Also have a look at our [FAQ](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), sorry but product recommendations are off topic, voting to close.

Comment: Thanks! Foobar seems to be very much what I am looking for. Sorry I am new at super user, what is wrong with my question, why the -1? thanks

Comment: All SE sites discourage shopping or recommendation questions because they soon go obsolete.

Comment: That is interesting, Although any technology related question will be soon obsolete.

Comment: @EddyXP product recommendations are off topic, read the link I gave you in my previous comment. The -1 (not by me) reflects that.

Comment: @terdon, I understand, is there a forum for software/product related questions? BTW I tried Clementine and it is also very good. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I love Clementine :). Anyway, this is the kind of thing you could ask in [chat] its just off topic as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) does a good job with this. It will actively monitor the folders in your library.

It has a barebones look to it at first, but it's highly [customizable and skinnable](http://techsplurge.com/3316/15-foobar2000-skins-themes/). You can see what people have done on sites like DeviantArt and customize.org.

[image: Foobar2000 Preferences Media Library]

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox can watch your "library location" for new files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I believe this is only for Linux Distributions, I am looking for Win 7.